# Jquery get JSON data is not working

Tags: jquery

I have json data, i want to get this json file in jquery, I used this code :

```
$.getJSON("http://somewebsite.com/service/all.json", function(json){

  alert("JSON Data: " + json[3].name);

});
```

but if use local url ( "data/jsdata.json" ) it works norm! I don't understand why?

Comment: pls post an example of your response

Comment: please post headers and json data here

Comment: Maybe webserver cannot serve json file properly. Which webserver are you using? For IIS7 http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/

Comment: What is the existing structure of json ? Try console.log(json)

Comment: Does your "http://somewebsite.com/service/all.json" really have some json data.... Use Firebug and see what error is being generated..

Comment: if i use this url on web browser it works without errors

Answer (score 2):

Cross domain **JSON** requests are not allowed.  See this note from the `getJSON` documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

> - Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; **the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol**.
> - Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

What you need to do is use JSONP, but that is something that also needs to be utilized properly by the server.

Per the `getJSON` documentation, you can do that by appending a callback to your url:

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If "somewebsite" is not your own site, you will not be allowed to use AJAX to get datas.
This is because the SOP Same Origin Policy.
A way avoid this is the JSONP technology. But it is not all websites that provide a jsonp API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [JSONP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/), to get around cross-site-scripting security policies in browsers. Specifying a callback in the query string of the request is required, along with some special formatting of the response by your server.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do a cross-domain ajax request (which is far more complicated)

Consider to use JSONP, but firstly assure yourself that you are really needing this. I personally prefer a CURL approach server-side in this cases.

Anyway for cross domain with jQuery check out [THIS](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)